# Counting principles: Probability of at least one Ace in 5 cards, conceptual problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I understand that the easiest way to calculate the probability of at least one Ace would be to calculate $$ 1-P(\text{No aces}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}} $$

And I understand that it would also work if I calculate all the cases and add them, i.e. the sum of probabilities of exactly $k$ aces in 5 draws, with $k=1,2,3,4$
$$ P(\text{At least one Ace}) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}} + \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}} + \frac{\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}} + \frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

My problem is, why can't I think of the problem as "OK, I choose at least one Ace, so that's $ \binom{4}{1}$, so one card is out and from the remaining cards (which still include 3 aces), I pick 4 more cards which include anywhere between 0 and 3 extra aces, i.e. $\binom{51}{4}$, giving "
$$P(\text{At least one Ace}) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{51}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

They are not numerically the same, so I have no idea where my conceptual misunderstanding in this approach is. I considered the possibility that I was counting something twice but the ratio of the two answers is not an integer, so I'm lost. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with $\binom{4}{1}\binom{51}{3}$ is that it introduces orders to your countings. To illustrate, look at the case where two aces are selected; diamond and heart. The formula counts this case twice:

1. Case where diamond ace is chosen first and heart ace is part of the remaining three chosen cards
2. Case where heart ace is chosen first and diamond ace is part of the remaining three chosen cards

This is only one example, the formula counts other cases more than once as well. Consequently, you will have larger number compared to your other two solutions.

**Remarks**

Most of the time, we answer combinatorics problems incorrectly because we somehow count ordered set / combinations when the problems ask for unordered set / combinations, or vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

You are counting a hand with $k$ aces $k$ times, once for each card that is an ace. You can check that
$$\binom{4}{1} \binom{51}{4} = \binom{4}{1} \binom{48}{4} + 2\binom{4}{2} \binom{48}{3} + 3\binom{4}{3} \binom{48}{2} + 4\binom{4}{4} \binom{48}{1}.$$